# View outlet was not set? (Xcode)

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, nib, viewcontroller

When trying to run my iPhone app that I am currently building the build succeeds but the application crashes after the start up image and gives me an error that looks like this:

> 2011-04-06 20:31:38.562 My App[3438:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "GalleryView" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

I cannot figure out whats going on here.. Please help!

Answer (score 10):

In Interface Builder, with the GalleryView.xib file open, make sure you CTRL+drag from your File's owner to your view and set the file's owner view outlet.

Comment: Oh gosh well I feel dumb! Thanks a bunch!